# SQL server update dbo refresh

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellisense

How come SQL server 2014 intellisense doesn't recognize recently created database objects (E.g. view, table, etc.), yet a query can be ran using such objects? 
Is this a bug?

Comment: I suspect that the data used is cached at application load. Refreshing intellisense can usually be done using Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: Changing database context using the SSMS drop-down list will also refresh the IntelliSense cache.

Answer (score 1):

The intellisense cache is built when you open a connection in the Query Editor of SQL Server Management Studio. But unfortunately the intellisense cache is not rebuilt after creating objects, and hence it is not refreshed until you press the shortcut *Ctrl+Shift+R* suggested by Simon.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use a mouse, enter here

[image]